# Add publish directory to ccnet header.xml

Tags: build, cruisecontrol.net

I have a CruiseControl.net build that compiles all the binaries, creates an installation and publishes the install files and log files to a server location. 
The actual final directory name is dynamic to include the YYYYMMDD_HH_MM_SS in the path name.

```
Example: <server>\Path\2-Tuesday\MyBuild_2014_08_06_07_23_15
```

I include the publisher event to send emails to our development and QA teams. In this email I would like to include the publish path for the build to make it easier for users to find the build.

I believe I want to modify the header.xls file in /server/xls/
However, I am not certain how to include the path?

My publishing script is a powershell script. Below is a code snippet

```
    $dOfWeek = (Get-Date).dayofweek.toString()
    $date = Get-Date
    $n = [int]$date.dayofweek
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $publishDir.value -ChildPath "$n-$dOfWeek"
    $day = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
    $time = Get-Date -Format HH_mm_ss
    $pubFolder="Bld" + $day + "_" + $time 
    $publishPath=Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $pubFolder
```

Note that $publishDir is a parameter passed to the function that formats this.

How do I set this up so that I notify ccnet of this path, and how do I incorporate the value in header.xls?

Thank you.
Sincerely, 
Daniel Lee

Answer (score 0):

Use a file merge task to "notify" CC of your custom information. The information will show up in the CC xml build log. See:

[File Merge](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/File_Merge_Task)

Then edit header.xsl or compile.xsl to transform the new xml into html to show up in the build emails.